# How come $e^x-e^{-x}=0$ does not have a solution?

Tags: exponential-function

While solving a partial differential equation following [this](https://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-PDE%20pt1.pdf) document, they state that

$$e^{\sigma L}-e^{-\sigma L}=0$$

does not have a solution and ask why. Here $L$ is a constant and $\sigma$ is a variable.

I'm not sure why this equation does not have a solution because when I plot $e^x-e^{-x}=0$ it crosses the $x$-axis. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If:
$$e^x-e^{-x}=0$$
$$e^x=e^{-x}$$
so the general solution is:
$$x=-x$$
$$\therefore x=0$$
However, if there was a limitation such as $x>0$ then there would be no solution (in this range)

Answer (score 3):

On page 13 they clearly state that they consider first the case

- $\lambda <0 \Rightarrow \sigma = \sqrt{-\lambda} > 0$.

For $\sigma > 0$ the given equation does not have a solution.

Note, that the given equation is equivalent to $e^{2\sigma L} = 1 \Rightarrow \sigma = 0$, which is excluded in the given case.

Answer (score 1):

Your document assumes $\sigma > 0$ so the only real solution $\sigma = 0$ is not admissible.

Answer (score 0):

The unknown is $\sigma$. Immediately, you get that $\sigma=0$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps they mean no *non-trivial* solution: if you balance the equation into a left and right side and take the logarithm, you are looking for the solution of $\sigma=-\sigma$, which for $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}$ is just zero.

Answer (score 0):

In any other instance, that equation does have a solution, $\sigma=0$. However, note that right above in your document, they stipulate that $\sigma>0$. As $0$ is not greater than itself, there is no $\sigma$ which solves that equation for the values of interest.